# Exceptions not thrown in web api

Tags: visual-studio, exception, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Web Api and when an exception happens in my code (for example a bad cast), and the debugger is attached, the exception is not thrown in Visual Studio. I just get the 500 internal server error on the browser side with the exception details but it's a pain because I have to track down what line it's thrown on.

I don't believe this was always the case, and thought it must be one of my settings messed up but I have already tried to reset visual studio settings to no avail.

How can I get the debugger to break again on 500 internal server errors.. I don't want to enable first chance exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, Ensure that "Enable Just My Code" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio Debug->Exceptions for exceptions that you need or for all of them select checkbox in the Throw column. It's because by default Asp.Net runtime handles all exceptions. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165012.aspx)